# Migrating from Actions SDK 2 to 3: Custom actions cannot be specified in projects which are not created using custom category

Tags: actions-on-google, google-assistant

I have a Google Action that is deployed to production (live) and was created with the old version of the Actions SDK where you have the action package, the so called 2nd version of the Actions SDK. My Action doesn't use Dialogflow so there is no migration button or whatsoever in the Actions console to perform a migration.

What I have tried is to use the new gactions.exe and just pull the current version of my Action. After just pulling I tried to push it back into my Google Action but the console output said "Actions project must specify at least one action in actions.yaml." So I added a custom action, but now the console output says that:

"Custom actions cannot be specified in projects which are not created using custom category."

I don't know how to resolve the issue, as I think that that error message isn't related to the Action's category "EDUCATION_AND_REFERENCE"?

Any help is very much appreciated on how to resolve the issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I figured out on my own how to migrate from an old (legacy) Google Action (v2) that haven't linked to/used a Dialogflow project to the new Conversational Action (v3).

I posted it separately as a guide: [Guide: Migrate from an old (legacy) Google Action (v2) to the new Conversational Action (v3) if your Action isn't connected to Dialogflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68191495/guide-migrate-from-an-old-legacy-google-action-v2-to-the-new-conversational)

Answer (score 0):

gactions v3 is exclusively used for Actions SDK v3, or the latest version of Actions SDK that is reflected in the Actions Console as Actions Builder. As such, legacy Actions SDK projects cannot be accessed using this CLI. You would need to use gactions v2 to perform your operations.

Additionally, you'd need to manually migrate your project to the new Actions SDK platform if you want to take advantage of the new gactions executable.

Comment: Thank you for your feedback, how can I manually migrate my project to the new Actions SDK platform? Do I have to update the action package of my Action with gactions v2 in a special way in order to migrate it then with the gactions v3 to the new Actions SDK?